# Sql Timeout com WebMatrix.Data.Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Utilizando o namespace WebMatrix.Data.Database, estou tendo problemas ao executar uma consulta que retorna muitos dados, resultando num Timeout.

Como posso aumentar o timeout desta consulta?

Exemplo do código:

```
var db = WebMatrix.Data.Database.Open("DefaultConnection");

var resultado = db.Query(consulta); //Timeout na execução desta consulta

return resultado.ToList().Count;
```

Web.config

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data
Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DefaultDB;User Id=foo;Password=bar;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Consigo alterar o timeout apenas do tempo de conexão, mas não consigo encontrar a propriedade para alterar o timeout da consulta realizada.

Answer (score 1):

Você já tentou algo como

```
"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=database;Connect Timeout=15"
```

Ou então alterar o default do sql Server usando sp_configure

Veja essa questão: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3091919